# Capturing log files generated by cmake within singularity image before the image cleans up after failed build

Tags: cmake, singularity-container

I'm building an application using a Singularity (v. 2.5.1) recipe file.  At some point it fails during the build, `cmake` fails and writes a errors to a log file within the singularity image.

To build the image :

```
sudo /opt/singularity/2.5.1/bin/singularity build test.simg Singularity
```

The end of the stdout output (printed to terminal) from the build is :

```
.
.
.
MKL is found at /my_dir/intel/mkl
CMake Error at cmake/FindMKL.cmake:83 (error):
  Unknown CMake command "error".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:262 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/my_dir/code/gadgetron/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

The problem is that since the singularity image build failed, there isn't an image to investigate the logs.

QUESTION : How do I preserve the logs or files from the build process when the image itself fails to build?  Perhaps there is a way in cmake to redirect the output from CMakeOutput.log to stdout?

Comment: You got an error on **configuration** stage. So this stage fails, and no **build** stage is ever performed. I am not familiar with singularity, but I guess the images are not generated before the build stage.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to bind or copy out the file before the singularity build attempt failed.

Comment: Oh, just found that you want the **logs**, not *images*. But if you want the logs for fix given error, then this has no sence. Everything related to the error is reported by CMake to configuration log, which you have shown.

Comment: There should be more information about the error in `/my_dir/code/gadgetron/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log`, correct?

Comment: Not quite true. CMake prints "See also" line in case of any error. But in most cases that `CMakeOutput.log` is *useless* for resolve the error. That log may (probably!) help if the error comes from CMake internals. But the error `Unknown CMake command "XXX".` isn't reflected in the log at all. The log does not list all available commands (at least, until debug options are specified for CMake). **In short**: It is better to firstly look into the specified line, and only then decide, whether you need additional information from CMake.

Comment: hi @irritable_phd_syndrome, any news about logs when building?